# How to remove indentation errors in Vim while keeping syntax checking?

Tags: php, vim, syntax, syntax-error, syntax-highlighting

I am using Syntastic in Vim to highlight syntax errors. However, it also shows so called indentation errors. I am not interested in these, and I find them annoying. How can I remove this feature while keeping syntax checking?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure this is from Syntastic? Because it's not like I've ever seen Syntastic do. Providing some example text where this happens would be good (see [mcve]), you can try [following these steps](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/51), and you can get the name of the syntax group with something like `:echo synIDattr(synID(line('.'), col('.'), 1), 'name')`.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Thank you for your comment. I am not sure whether this is from Syntastic. I provided a screenshot of text where you can see the red highlighted part (which is the indentation). This occurs only in some cases, but many times in a long file.

Answer (score 0):

You do not state which programming language this is. Syntastic calls different external tools for each language. How you can selectively silence certain messages is stated in the [Official Syntastic FAQ](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic#faqstyle).

For example, to suppress all messages from style checkers, use this:

```
let g:syntastic_quiet_messages = { "type": "style" }
```

Comment: The programming language is PHP.